# How to reduce (or simplify) a power series

Tags: power-series

So I have the following power series from my book and I am trying to reduce it. I became a bit confused about how to reduce it and was wondering how you would go about simplifying it.

[image: Power series for estimating square root of 2]

Answer (score 1):

Start with the known generating function of the central binomial coefficients:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2 k}{k} z^k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4 z}}.$$
Differentiate with respect to $z$ and multiply by $z$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k \binom{2 k}{k} z^k = \frac{2z}{(1 - 4 z)^{3/2}}.$$

Now the original sum is
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k+1)!}{2^{3k+1}k!^2} 
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1) \binom{2 k}{k} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\binom{2 k}{k} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^k
+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2 k}{k} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^k\\
&= \frac{2(1/8)}{(1 - 4(1/8))^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4(1/8)}}\\
&= \frac{1/4}{(1/2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1/2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{2}.
\end{align}